# ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED on WIndows 11 Chrome

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, nginx, inertiajs

I have a problem with ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED when one starts playing audio file on the site and then clicks any link on the page. It’s not happening all the time but sometimes happens and only on Chromium based browser on Windows.
Website is on Laravel and Vue.js + Inertia.js. Small audio files, less than 1 Mb. I use simple Html5 player like

```
        <audio controls class=“py-2” preload=“auto”>
            <source :src=“`/storage/audio/${filename}`” type=“audio/wav”>
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
```

Server is based on nginx. May be someone has any idea what the problem can be?

Comment: consider check extensions, specially ad blockers.